# Сравнить double [Си]

Tags: c

Как правильно сравнить double?
Не хочет правильно сравнивать =(

Comment: Классический текст по теме вопроса: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Или поменьше, но [тоже по теме](http://www.johndcook.com/IEEE_exceptions_in_cpp.html)

Comment: И вопрос классический. Минус автору -- вопрос демонстрирует явное неуважение к аудитории. "У меня есть проблема -- догадайтесь какая и предложите решение"

Answer (score 10):

Ну классика жанра. Никогда не сравнивайте вещественные значения на равенство. В большинстве случаев не выйдет.

Правильно сравнивать модуль разницы двух значений с неким эпсилом (достаточно маленьким значением).

```
if (fabs(f1-f2) > 1e-6) {
   std::cout << "больше";
}
```

Если нужно сравнивать на равенство, то условие просто изменяется.

Comment: IMHO, однако, следует заметить, что одна и та же последовательность операций над одними и теми же операндами **всегда** даст одинаковый результат и (кроме, конечно, NaN и INF) результат сравнения будет true.

Comment: на одной машине, в стирильных условиях.

Но не забывайте, что даже для процессоров есть обновления микрокода (по крайней мере для Intel). И как не вспомнить [баг](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_Pentium_FDIV).

Поэтому, нельзя настаивать на том, что результат предсказуемый. В один прекрасный момент это может быть не так. Для развлечений использовать можно, а в реальном коде - только в исключительных ситуациях.

Comment: Хм, работает.
Можете оставить свои контактные данные для пары вопросов в ПМ?

Comment: Куда оно денется, так задумано изначально. Если сильно хочется связаться - просто найдите мой аккаунт в гуглтолке. угадать его можно по нику.

Comment: @KoVadim баг 1994 года... Археолог, однако. Начальник партии. А какие тогда были анекдоты.

     -- Почему у Intel 80286, 80386, 80486, а дальше -- P5?
     -- А когда они прибавили 100 к 80486, то получилось 80585.999999999997

Comment: Но баг то зачетный. Я конечно за то, что бы в процессорах не было ошибок, и ложечки нашлись, но осадочек...

Comment: Где-то в те же времена был ещё один громкий баг в пентиуме, F00F. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/F0_0F_C7_C8